# Repeating function that appends to list

Tags: python-2.7

How can I explain this...

I am new to Python and currently use the latest version of Python 2.

I am writing (or attempting to write) a program that logs productions and adds the productions to a list. My aim is to repeatedly prompt the user to add productions until they select 'No', thereafter the program should move on to the next phase.

So far I have defined a function that asks the user if they would like to log a production, then asks for the production name, description and result. The respective lists are then updated with the user's input.

Where I am failing is that I can't get the program to then ask the user if they would like to add another production, and then close the loop if they select 'No'.

Here is my code:

```
locus = raw_input('Enter location where statement compiled: ')
colleague = raw_input('Enter name of corroborating officer: ')
productions = []
descriptions = []
result = []

def logger():
    log = raw_input('Would you like to log a production? Y or N: ')
    if log == 'Y' or 'y':
        new_production = raw_input('ENTER NAME OF PRODUCTION: ')
        productions.append(new_production)  
        new_description = raw_input('ENTER DESCRIPTION OF PRODUCTION: ') 
        descriptions.append(new_description)
        new_result = raw_input('ENTER SUMMARY OF CONTENTS FOUND: ')
        result.append(new_result)
        print new_production
        print new_description
        print new_result    
        return True
    else:
        return False

logger()

while True:
    finished = raw_input('Do you want to submit another? Y or N: ')
    if finished == 'Y' or 'y':
        logger()
    else:
        return False
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input('Would you like to enter a new log? Y or N: ')
    if inp.lower() == "y":
        # do your required functions to create a log in here
        # or you could call logger(), as long as you modify it appropriately
        new_production = raw_input('ENTER NAME OF PRODUCTION: ')
        ...
        print new_description
        print new_result    
    elif inp.lower() == "n":
        break
    else:
        print "invalid response"
```

Let me know if you would like an explanation for any of it!

Comment: That seems to have worked perfectly and is just what I was after - can you give me feedback as to where I was going wrong or any other advice re my coding above? Thanks.

Comment: The way you were writing your loop wasn't bad, just perhaps not as concise as it could be. Also, when trying to stop running a loop, you should `break`. Previously, it looks like you were doing `return False` - but only functions can return values. This also has no impact on the loop. Otherwise the rest of your code is pretty good! Glad I could help, please do mark the answer as correct (the green tick) if this is what you were looking for!